# Error while processing a persisted job checkDuplicateCSetKey

Tags: wso2

```
TID: [-1] [] [2019-11-22 13:18:34,362]  WARN {org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler} -  Error while processing a persisted job: Job hqejbhcnphreqf4l2mpcoj time: 2019-11-22 13:18:31 WEST transacted: true persisted: true details: JobDetails( instanceId: null mexId: hqejbhcnphreqf4l2mpcoi processId: {http://wso2.org/bps/sample}my-process-7 type: INVOKE_INTERNAL channel: null correlatorId: null correlationKeySet: null retryCount: 4 inMem: false detailsExt: {enqueue=false}) {org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.checkDuplicateCSetKey(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:621)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.checkDuplicateCSets(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:578)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.runtime.PICK$WAITING$2.onRequestRcvd(PICK.java:300)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1427.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU$JacobThreadImpl.run(JacobVPU.java:451)
    at org.apache.ode.jacob.vpu.JacobVPU.execute(JacobVPU.java:139)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelRuntimeContextImpl.execute(BpelRuntimeContextImpl.java:1002)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.invokeNewInstance(PartnerLinkMyRoleImpl.java:208)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess$1.invoke(BpelProcess.java:283)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:224)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.invokeProcess(BpelProcess.java:279)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelProcess.handleJobDetails(BpelProcess.java:434)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.sendMyRoleFault(BpelEngineImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelEngineImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelEngineImpl.java:581)
    at org.apache.ode.bpel.engine.BpelServerImpl.onScheduledJob(BpelServerImpl.java:467)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:633)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:627)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:298)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:253)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:627)
    at org.apache.ode.scheduler.simple.SimpleScheduler$RunJob.call(SimpleScheduler.java:611)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(T
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the data:

1. A BPEL process had 3 versions (v1, v2, v3)
2. Version v1 has been removed (from the registry and bpel / -123) but these instances still remained in the database
3. An old instance of version v1 remained in ACTIVE status with an id correlation = 400200 (for example).
4. When starting a new instance of version v3 with a correlation id = 400200 the exception is raised.

Indeed apache ODE to each new instance looks for if there is an instance in active status and carrying the same correlation id (checkDuplicatCS ..). In our context, Apache ODE finds an instance of version v1 and goes back NullpointerException because it does not find the process v1 in its registry.

Solution: Clean the old instances in Active status of version v1.